# Running Tensorflow undefined symbol: PyClass_Type

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow

I have been Googling everywhere and I can't find the answer to this problem.  I am following this Git: https://github.com/thunlp/TensorFlow-Summarization. When I run "python3 script/train.py" I get the following error:

~~~~~~

```
$ python script/test.py
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
>   "/home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 243, in
>   load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 343, in
>   load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: /home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so:
>   undefined symbol: PyClass_Type
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "script/test.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import tensorflow as tf   File "/home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import   File
>   "/home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "/home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
>   "/home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 243, in
>   load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 343, in
>   load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: /home/vedant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so:
>   undefined symbol: PyClass_Type
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

~~~~~~

My operating system is Linux (Manjaro). I appreciate any help :)

Comment: how did you install tensorflow? It seems you have a python2 compiled tensorflow running in python3, and that obviously won't work.

Comment: I ran the pacman installer and git cloned the tensorflow repository

Comment: How can I run it in python2 or install the python3 version on Manjaro?

Comment: Please answer in detail, what is the pacman installer? Did you install tensorflow like pacman -S python-tensorflow ?

Comment: I typed sudo pacman -S python-tensorflow, sudo pacman -S tensorflow, and 
sudo git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git (all separately)